# How to copy an add on of android sdk to android android sdk

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me the steps to copy an installed add on in android sdk to android android sdk.

My problem is now that add on is not available in google now(this is pretty old sdk).

Now I want to copy this add on to new sdk so that while creating new android project, it will ask to create project based on this add on. Can anyone tell me how can I do this?

**UPDATE**

To clarify more, in my old sdk api level 9 is installed but now its not available. So I want to add this api level 9 to new sdk so that when I create new Android project, it should give me option to create project with api level 9

Comment: I cannot understand your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done. If you download sdk components, then only it will be available in avd manager.

Answer (score 1):

Extract your new add-on for ex **ADT18.zip** open plugins folder copy all **jar** files
go to

`eclipse -> plugins` folder paste all your jar files here.

restart eclipse...